# How to retrieve the image in a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file-upload

**Hello !**

---

### Context

I created products using a form where I ask the admin to give obligatorily: a name, a price ... an image

This is what the form looks like :

[image: Product Form]

I only save the name of the image in my database under the "PRO_URL" column

I manage very well to retrieve my image on my home page showing all the available products.
The admin also has the option to modify a product, to do this, I use the same form as to create a product.
I manage to recover in my fields thanks to "value" the values ​​of the product EXCEPT the image.

Again this is what the form looks like with the data in it :

[image: Product Form with Data retrieved in it]

The file input is still empty.

---

To send the product information to my form, I send it via a React-router Link containing in the URL the id of the product to be modified.

And I get it all like this :

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if (id) {
            getProduitById(id).then(response => {
                if (response.data){
                    setProduit({
                        nom: response.data.nom,
                        prix: response.data.prix,
                        description: response.data.description,
                        imageurl: response.data.imageurl, 
                        qtestock: response.data.qtestock,
                        marqueId: response.data.marqueId,
                    })
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }, [])
```

---

Each product image is stored in my project under public, UUID renames them to be unique :

[image: public with images]

I read that the input element of type file is uncontrolled so that the site cannot take the image on our computer.
As I save the image there must be a way so that I can use the url or name of my image for my modified product

Comment: Its unclear where you're asking help with. What does retrieve an image in a form mean? Are you trying to show the image that the user uploads before sending it? Or trying to show the image that has been uploaded in the edit view?

Comment: I'm trying to show the image that has been uploaded in the edit view. So the admin can change for example the price of the product without uploading, again, the image. Sorry if my title is unclear ... I wasn't to sure how to explain it.

Comment: That's okay. Render the image in an `<img>` next to the file input when you are in the editing view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to render on frontend without getting response from backend you can do it like this

```
URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
```

Otherwise if your want to render image from response you need to  first **generate URL of your image**. You can do this by using any cloud service where you upload you file at backend and then get that URL i.e CLOUDINARY, our you can use MULTER to save file in you project directory and generate URL or try other npm packages.